# How to truncate time on java.sql.Date?

Tags: java, date

I have the following code:

```
String dateCompleted = "4/24/2009 2:38:44 PM";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
java.util.Date tempDate = format.parse(dateCompleted);
java.sql.Date completionDate = new java.sql.Date(tempDate.getTime());
```

I want to compare `completionDate` to a DATE value in an Oracle database table that does not include time. For example, I want to compare it to the value '4/24/2009' and have it return true, because these dates are the same.

How do I truncate the time value from my variable in order to compare it to the database value? Thanks in advance!

Comment: delete hh:mm:ss a from format string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String dateCompleted = "4/24/2009 2:38:44 PM";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
java.util.Date tempDate = format.parse(dateCompleted);
java.sql.Date completionDate = new java.sql.Date(tempDate.getTime());
```

same as mentioned by @sgpalit.

Answer (score 5):

Apache Commons Lang has a date truncation method you can use for this:

```
java.util.Date truncated = DateUtils.truncate(tempDate, Calendar.DATE);
```

see the Javadocs for [`DateUtils.truncate`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#truncate(java.util.Date,%20int)) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

define the SimpleDateFormat objects as follows,

```
DateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private final Pattern timeSection = Pattern.compile("\\s+.+?:.*");

String stripTime(String dateStringWithTime){
   Matcher m = timeSection.matcher(dateStringWithTime);
   if(m.find()){
      return m.replaceAll("");
   }
   return dateStringWithTime;
}
```